# Jenkins: "Docker client wasn't initialized"

Tags: plugins, jenkins, docker

I am trying to run the docker plugin in Jenkins but I get the error:

```
[Docker] ERROR: docker client is not initialized, command 'Pull image' was aborted. Check Jenkins server log which Docker client wasn't initialized
```

What does that mean? I have installed docker on the machine that runs jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

There could be two reasons for that.

1. you need to make sure that docker is really up and running on jenkins server

`which docker`

2. make sure that your url is added in the global configuration for jenkins

`manage jenkins -> configure system -> Docker Url`

You can just set it to localhost:port on where your docker is listening.  If you didn't set up docker to listen to tcp or you didn't know that docker offers REST api, check out http://blog.trifork.com/2013/12/24/docker-from-a-distance-the-remote-api/.  It'll get you on the right path.